# Problemas com CORS no Django utilizando AWS S3

Tags: django, cors, amazon-aws

Minha aplicação utiliza um bucket na AWS para hospedar os arquivos estáticos e de MEDIA, eis o link: http://memoriasclubeturismoenv.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/gilson-rolim-02-12-2019 ou https://memorias.clubeturismo.com.br/gilson-rolim-02-12-2019

Na minha aplicação utilizo um plugin chamado "[Dearflip](https://dearflip.com/)".

O problema é que, por algum motivo, mesmo configurando o CORS no bucket, continua dando problema ao executar o plugin.

O erro é este: Access to image at 'https://media-memorias.s3.amazonaws.com/media/models/Capa_mvd8KiC.png' from origin 'http://memoriasclubeturismoenv.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Adicionei o seguinte no bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como solucionar este mistério?

Comment: Tentou usar o https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/ ?

Comment: Sim, mas não funcionou, infelizmente :(

Comment: Mas vc só instalou e não fez a config do `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`? Pq se não aplicar ele não faz nada

Comment: Sim, eu adicionei os hots ao CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST mas não deu certo :(

Comment: O erro é: Access to image at 'https://media-memorias.s3.amazonaws.com/media/models/Capa_bRI7lVR.png' from origin 'https://memorias.clubeturismo.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Atualmente o django-cors-headers está em uso e, no settings.py, adicionei o seguinte: CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

Comment: Olhando bem acho que não vai dar certo, dá uma nisto: https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct#access-setup

Answer (score 0):

Creio que apenas baste adicionar mais uma linha na configuracao do Bucket

```
<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
```

para testar correctamente, eu vou à pagina www.jquery.com, abro a consola e digito:

```
$.get('https://media-memorias.s3.amazonaws.com/media/models/Capa_mvd8KiC.png', 
  data => console.log(data) );
```

e correctamente, mostra o erro CORS

> ```
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://media-memorias.s3.amazonaws.com/media/models/Capa_mvd8KiC.png'
> from origin 'https://jquery.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
> ```

para teste, copiei a sua imagem e coloquei no meu novo bucket, e tambem mostrou o erro, mas depois de o configurar com `HEAD` logo deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Se eu editiar o seu Array de imagens e meter o meu link, vejo tudo certo tambem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

apenas modifiquei a variavel `option_button_image` que tem no final da pagina para que contenha o meu link...

Comment: Adicionei o <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod> mas não deu certo :(, o mais estranho é que a mesma imagem abre na pagina, mas quando inicia o plugin, não funciona.

Comment: @VictorFernandes mas agora com o `HEAD` vejo todas as outras images que nao conseguia antes ;) já desfolheaste o "livro"?

Comment: Esse é que é o estranho, as outras imagens abrem, exceto a primeira. Quando clico para folhear, apenas a primeira imagem não aparece aqui. Você consegue visualizar todas?

Comment: faz o seguinte, apaga a imagem, e volta a fazer o upload, até mesmo com outro nome, muda no codigo e tenta ... sim todas as outras imagens conseigo excepto a capa... mas se apagares e voltares a meter-la no bucket pode dar resultado...

Comment: Fiz isso, alterei a imagem pela aplicação, mas, novamente, não deu certo :'(

Comment: só para ver se é da-coisa... faz o seguinte: mete 2 imagens da capa com nomes diferentes, usa um dos nomes na imagem de inicio, usa o outro nome no Array de imagens... e vê se funciona...

Comment: Ja tentei renomear o arquivo, mas não vai, e já reparei que é só na capa, no conteudo e na contra-capa não da problema.

É assim que populo o array: var option_button_image = {source: ["{{ object.model.cover.url }}",{% for x, y in images %}"{{ x.page.url }}","{{ y.url }}",{% endfor %}"{{ object.model.back_cover.url }}"]}; Onde o cover é a capa, e o back_cover é a contra-capa.